# Can anyone guide me in the usage of the ClientCredential(String, ISecureClientSecret) option of constructor for Dynamics 365?

Tags: c#, authentication, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I know I have to create a class which would implement the ISecureClietSecret interface which has the ApplyTo function which takes an IDictionary of two strings as parameters. But what are these strings supposed to be? What is the purpose of this function that needs to be implemented?

I do see that the IDictionary is the "Dictionary to which the securestring is applied to be sent to server" but I am just unclear as to how to go about this. Could anybody kindly guide me?

Below is the link which mentions the two constructors.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.clientcredential.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet